# My Metamask Wallt just spins when clicked and doesnt connect

Tags: metamask

I have an old version of metamask 4.1?? on a computer running windows 7.   When i click on metamask, it just spins.  My last login was about 2 yrs ago.  What do i need to do to login to wallet?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try updating the browser and metamask?